# Play piano keys through Bluetooth LE and Midi

Tags: bluetooth, python-2.x, midi

### On the desktop

Using my desktop Macbook I can successfully "remote-play" notes on my piano through the USB-Midi to Bluetooth adapter (Yamaha UD-BT01).

First I pair the device through the **Audio Midi Setup** application:

[image: connect piano]

Then I run the following python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pygame.midi # pip install pygame
import time

pygame.midi.init()

output_id = pygame.midi.get_default_output_id()
print pygame.midi.get_device_info(output_id)
# Output: 
# ('CoreMIDI', 'UD-BT01 Bluetooth', 0, 1, 0)

player = pygame.midi.Output(output_id)
player.set_instrument(0)
player.note_on(90, 64)
time.sleep(1)
player.note_off(90, 64)
del player
pygame.midi.quit()
```

And instantly I hear the note being played on my piano.

### On the Raspberry PI

On the PI I did install [bluez-5.49](http://www.bluez.org/download/) from source using [adafruits tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/install-bluez-on-the-raspberry-pi/installation).

So now using the `bluetoothctl` I see the bluetooth device and I can pair and connect to it.

```
[UD-BT01]# info
Device E3:43:29:85:A3:F0 (random)
    Name: UD-BT01
    Alias: UD-BT01
    Paired: yes
    Trusted: yes
    Blocked: no
    Connected: yes
    LegacyPairing: no
    UUID: Generic Access Profile    (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Device Information        (0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Vendor specific           (03b80e5a-ede8-4b33-a751-6ce34ec4c700)
```

Also the `lsusb` command shows the connected bluetooth adapter:

> Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)

Now if I run the same script in the python console I do not get an error but I can't hear a sound. Also the output does not show the device name but it prints the following:

```
('ALSA', 'Midi Through Port-0', 0, 1, 0)
```

While with the working setup on my mac I get:

```
('CoreMIDI', 'UD-BT01 Bluetooth', 0, 1, 0)
```

So now I am wondering how to get this working on my Raspberry PI.

#### Update: Similar results with RtMidi

I tried another lbirary [pyrtmidi](https://github.com/patrickkidd/pyrtmidi/) and this would allow me to detect piano keys being pressed on my mac but again not on the raspberry pi.